# Convert long string in multiple short strings in a for loop in Python (OpenPyXL Module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to convert my config (long-string) into multiple short strings in an Excel-file but this is where I am stuck:

**Long-string**

```
edit 20 set status enable set sender-pattern-type default set sender-pattern * set recipient-pattern-type default set recipient-pattern * set sender-ip-type ip-group set sender-ip-group TEST-GROUP-10.x.x.x/24 set reverse-dns-pattern * set reverse-dns-pattern-regexp no set authenticated any unset tls-profile set action relay set comment 10.x.x.x/24 next edit 21 ... ... ... .. next edit 22 ...
```

**What I want**

```
A1    edit 20 set status enable set sender-pattern-type default set sender-pattern * set recipient-pattern-type default set recipient-pattern * set sender-ip-type ip-group set sender-ip-group TEST-GROUP-10.x.x.x/24 set reverse-dns-pattern * set reverse-dns-pattern-regexp no set authenticated any unset tls-profile set action relay set comment 10.x.x.x/24 next
A2 edit 21 ... ... ... .. next 
A3 edit 22 ... next
```

**Current code:**

```
# Long-config output
output = ssh_stdout.readlines()

# Open Workbook
wb = load_workbook('Firewall-config.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Create a workbook sheet name.
sheet = wb['Sheet']

start_row = 1

for line in output:
                ws.cell(row=start_row, column=1, value =line)
                start_row += 1

wb.save("Firewall-config.xlsx")
```

**What I have inside my Excel-file:**

```
    A1  edit 29
    
    A2    set status enable
    
    A3    set sender-pattern-type default
    
    etc.    set sender-pattern *
    
    A13  next
    
    A14  edit 38
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex, something like:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "edit 9 abc def edit 10 ... ... .. next edit 11 ..."
>>> a = re.split('(edit [0-9]+) ', s)
>>> a[1::2]
['edit 9', 'edit 10', 'edit 11']
>>> a[2::2]
['abc def ', '... ... .. next ', '...']
```